# How to make user as an exposed filter option in filter criteria of a normal view?

Tags: 7, users, views

In a view, I want list of users of specific role to be exposed filter option, which will list all users of that role.

**Example:** What I want is in view type like order or customer of ubercart(example), I want user to be filter criteria with exposed filter option of specific role(buyer or seller). If i select one user that particular user order should be listed.

Is that possible?? If so then how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may install this module [Total Control](https://drupal.org/project/total_control) module. After installing this module goto this link **yourdomain.com/admin/structure/views/view/control_users/edit**

This view provides the functionality you want.

To see it working you visit the page through this link **yourdomain.com/admin/dashboard/users**

**EDIT** I have export the view and pasted it below in-case you just need a reference and don't want to install that module.

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'control_users';
$view->description = 'Total Control over user accounts: Contains a panel pane and a page to control user accounts.';
$view->tag = 'total_control';
$view->base_table = 'users';
$view->human_name = '';
$view->core = 0;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Defaults */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Defaults', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'User Accounts';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['perm'] = 'have total control';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['options']['query_comment'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['submit_button'] = 'Filter';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '35';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['id'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['columns'] = array(
  'name' => 'name',
  'mail' => 'mail',
  'rid' => 'rid',
  'status' => 'status',
  'created' => 'created',
  'login' => 'login',
  'delete_node' => 'delete_node',
  'edit_node' => 'edit_node',
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default'] = '-1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['info'] = array(
  'name' => array(
    'sortable' => 1,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'mail' => array(
    'sortable' => 1,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'rid' => array(
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'status' => array(
    'sortable' => 1,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'created' => array(
    'sortable' => 1,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'login' => array(
    'sortable' => 1,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'delete_node' => array(
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'edit_node' => array(
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
);
/* Field: Bulk operations: User */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['id'] = 'views_bulk_operations';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['field'] = 'views_bulk_operations';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['display_type'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['enable_select_all_pages'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['force_single'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['entity_load_capacity'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_operations'] = array(
  'action::user_block_user_action' => array(
    'selected' => 1,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::views_bulk_operations_delete_item' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::views_bulk_operations_script_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::views_bulk_operations_modify_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
    'settings' => array(
      'show_all_tokens' => 1,
      'display_values' => array(
        '_all_' => '_all_',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'action::views_bulk_operations_user_roles_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::views_bulk_operations_argument_selector_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
    'settings' => array(
      'url' => '',
    ),
  ),
  'action::system_send_email_action' => array(
    'selected' => 1,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 1,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
);
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
/* Field: User: E-mail */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['id'] = 'mail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['field'] = 'mail';
/* Field: User: Roles */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rid']['id'] = 'rid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rid']['table'] = 'users_roles';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rid']['field'] = 'rid';
/* Field: User: Created date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['label'] = 'Created';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['date_format'] = 'custom';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['custom_date_format'] = 'm/d/Y';
/* Field: User: Last login */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['login']['id'] = 'login';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['login']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['login']['field'] = 'login';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['login']['date_format'] = 'custom';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['login']['custom_date_format'] = 'j/d g:ia';
/* Field: User: Edit link */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['edit_node']['id'] = 'edit_node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['edit_node']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['edit_node']['field'] = 'edit_node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['edit_node']['label'] = 'Edit';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['edit_node']['text'] = 'edit';
/* Sort criterion: User: Created date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid']['operator'] = 'not in';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid']['value'] = array(
  0 => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid']['expose']['label'] = 'User: Name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid']['expose']['operator'] = 'uid_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid']['expose']['identifier'] = 'uid';
/* Filter criterion: User: Roles */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['rid']['id'] = 'rid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['rid']['table'] = 'users_roles';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['rid']['field'] = 'rid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['rid']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['rid']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'rid_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['rid']['expose']['label'] = 'Roles';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['rid']['expose']['operator'] = 'rid_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['rid']['expose']['identifier'] = 'rid';
/* Filter criterion: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_1']['id'] = 'uid_1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_1']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_1']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_1']['value'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_1']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_1']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'uid_1_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_1']['expose']['label'] = 'Username';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_1']['expose']['operator'] = 'uid_1_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_1']['expose']['identifier'] = 'name';
/* Filter criterion: User: E-mail */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['mail']['id'] = 'mail';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['mail']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['mail']['field'] = 'mail';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['mail']['operator'] = 'contains';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['mail']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['mail']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'mail_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['mail']['expose']['label'] = 'E-mail';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['mail']['expose']['operator'] = 'mail_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['mail']['expose']['identifier'] = 'mail';

/* Display: User Admin */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'User Admin', 'page_1');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['hide_admin_links'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'admin/dashboard/users';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'tab';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'User Accounts';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '-14';
```

Comment: I dont want this. What i want is in view type like order or customer of ubercart(example), i want user to be filter criteria with exposed filter option of specific role.@fahad.